# Modifying GRUB Boot Paths

Tags: linux, boot, grub, linux-mint

I am trying to change the boot path in GRUB for Windows.

I found [this website](https://electrictoolbox.com/linux-grub-boot-loader-options/#:%7E:text=Open%20up%20the%20file%20using%20a%20text%20editor)(go passed the two pictures of the Fedora GRUB menu) that show how to edit the grub menu, but for some reason, it doesn't load that file... it says it doesn't exist...

I know that website was talking about Fedora, but I assumed that the file would exist on my machine (Linux Mint).

Does this kind of file exist in other Linux Distros?
- If so, what is the path for that file in Linux Mint?
- If not, is there an equivalent file?

Comment: Most people use Grub Customizer for this in Mint, it is in the repos

Comment: Also, you will find that GRUB and GRUB2 are VERY VERY different.  Linux mint uses GRUB2 I believe.. Anyone else a MINT fan care to chime in ???

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Yeah, Linux Mint uses GRUB2. I think some older versions may have used GRUB...